# 301 redirect to new page after slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I  have made some changes on my website structure and would like to use a perm redirect using .haccess

The old URL's:

```
http://domain.com/search/
http://domain.com/browse/
```

New URLS:

```
http://domain.com/search/searchevents/
http://domain.com/browse/eventlist
```

Have tried a few suggestions from other posts- but i have ended up with some loops going on!

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Jamie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/search/(.*)$ /search/searchevents/$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/browse/(.*)$ /search/eventlist/$1
```

If you have rewrite rules, you should probably not use mod_alias (the `RedirectMatch`) and stick with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /search/searchevents/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^browse/(.*)$ /search/eventlist/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - this caused the following:
    search/searchevents/searchevents/searchevents/searchevents/searchevents/searchevents/searchevents/searchevents/searchevents/searchevents/

Comment: @user3200168 try removing the `(.*)` and `$1` parts from the directives